# How to map entity property in Symfony form

Tags: symfony

I have an entity - 'house' I want to edit in a symfony form. One of the properties of the entity is another entity 'owner' mapped in a manytoone relationship.

When I create the House entity I know who owns it and that canlt be changed so I need to pass the owner in the form, but not in a way that can be edited.

If I wasn't using Symfony I would just pass it as an 'OwnerID' hidden field. In Symfony I know I can pass it as an entitity type but that is a choice field, visible and allows the owner to be changed.

So how should I pass it in symfony?

Simply adding it to the form as 'Owner' gives me an array to string conversion error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid the array to string conversion error you should make a `__toString()` function in order to print the OwnerId value.

Once there, you can add the disable property to the owner field as explain in this [doc](https://symfony.com/doc/3.0/reference/forms/types/entity.html#disabled)
in order to do that you need to set default values or insert some logic on submit actions.

Hope it works!

Comment: The REAL problem it turned out was that I populated the owner property I used the findBy() functiod and assigned the value returned to the property. the function returns and array of objects though, hence the Array to string conversion error. Using findOneBy() returned an owner class which then called the __toString() function successfully... unfortunately the persist at the other end didn't like having an integer and not a class. So this solved the problem I was having, but the real problem I was trying to fix.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the option :

> "disabled" => true

Documentation:
If you don't want a user to modify the value of a field, you can set the disabled option to true. Any submitted value will be ignored.

[Official documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/reference/forms/types/choice.html#disabled)

Comment: " Any submitted value will be ignored" is an odd one. Normally diabled value would not be posted with the form so using it as an uneditable way to pass the owner through the form wouldn't work... but for some reason in Symfony it does.